# How do I record test script of web application on localhost in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record the flow of my web application using Jmeter 5.1.1 templates in Mozilla Firefox, but it does not record flow for the web application. But when I test any application online then it works fine.

Comment: Do you have enabled the proxy also for localhost?

Comment: No I have not enabled the proxy for localhost. Should I enable it?

Comment: If you run your application on localhost yes, then you should enable it.

Answer (score 1):

I could able to solve this issue by following steps:

- Use **IPv4 address**instead of using localhost or 127.0.0.1 to access your local application. (you can get IPv4 address by opening command prompt and typing ipconfig)

  - Get JMeter's recording template from File > Template.
  - Set proxy on 8888 port and start recording.

Thank you !!! I hope this helps

Comment: Wow...Please up vote and accept this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to record your scenario with [BlazeMeter Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), you just have to sign up which is free and then you can learn how to record your script by referring [Record Jmeter script Using Blazemeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter-blazemeters-chrome-extension/)

Comment: yes I can record using BlazeMeter but I am participated in a contest in which the blazemeter is not allowed.